# Drools kieContainer fail to create

Tags: java, spring-boot, drools

i'm trying to follow the exact same steps on this

[Spring Boot Drools Rule Engine Example](https://medium.com/javarevisited/spring-boot-drools-rule-engine-example-965eea437ee9)

but I have this error at compilation time :

`Error creating bean with name 'kieContainer' defined in class path resource [.../DroolsConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer]: Factory method 'kieContainer' threw exception with message: Cannot invoke "org.drools.compiler.compiler.Dialect.getBuilder(java.lang.Class)" because the return value of "org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.RuleBuildContext.getDialect()" is null ...................`

those are the dependencies added to my pom.xml

````
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>8.33.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>8.33.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
            <version>8.33.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>```


I'm using spring boot 3

Thank you for your help!

I'm using java Records instead of normal class
````

Comment: Why is your drools-api version so ancient? it's definitely not compatible. Rule of thumb is that all your drools dependencies should be the same version.

Comment: Actually why do you have that dependency at all? I peeked at that article and while rather wordy and overly complicated, it doesn't include drools-api.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas 
  even i remove drools-api from the pom i still have the same error, i just added it to see if that resove the issue but it's not

Comment: do you have a simpler way to do thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by adding this dependency to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-mvel</artifactId>
            <version>version...</version>
</dependency>
```